# Mapping data with ajax returns zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've been working with ajax to get input values from a form when it's submitted, but when I look into the console it comes back as `0`. I'm not too familiar with ajax overall, so I'm not sure if I'm not using `this` correctly or if I have an error somewhere else.

Here's what I have:

**JS:**

```
jQuery(this).find(".form-item").on("submit", function(e) {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    if (this.checkValidity()) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: Config.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        accepts: 'application/json',
        context: this,
        data: {
          action: 'process_form',
          form_info: {
            "input_18_16": $(this).parents('.form-item').find('#input_18_16').val() || '',
            "input_18_17": $(this).parents('.form-item').find('#input_18_17').val() || '',
            "input_18_3": $(this).parents('.form-item').find('#input_18_3').val() || '',
            "input_18_2": $(this).parents('.form-item').find('#input_18_2').val() || ''
          },
        },
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
          console.log('Response:\n', data)
          console.log('successful trigger');
          console.log($(this).find('#input_18_16').val());
        },
        error: function(xhr, code, error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

The crazy thing is that I can get the data correctly from this:
`console.log($(this).find('#input_18_16').val());`
In the console. Which but for some reason the `console.log('Response:\n', data)` comes back as `Response:0` so I'm not sure why it's successful but not able to return anything?

Comment: You may be right, the `$(this)` at that point can be referring to the ajax call... If you are not sure if the `this` is pointing to the right element, print a property of it in the console...

Answer (score 0):

In the `success` function you should use `$this` instead of `$(this)`. That's why you set it in the first place, isn't it?

You can also use it in the `data:` option, since it's more efficient to reuse the variable instead of calling `jQuery()` repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

the data in 'console.log('Response:\n', data)' is actually being returned from the success function after ajax returns successful. Is is not the same as the data you are posting to  Config.ajaxurl.

Answer (score -1):

Check the missing ";" on the line  *console.log('Response:\n', data)*.
And I think the "\n" not affects the console.log mensage.

EGG: After this, checkout it https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ may be make your life more easy

Comment: I added the ; to the end of that console.log line and still comes back with 0.

Comment: Why would the missing `;` cause a problem? Javascript has Automatic Semicolon Insertion.